# Mark as read only all controls WPF

Tags: wpf, controls

OK this is an interesting one.

I have a wpf application with tabs. What I want to do is have a DB setting that turns off the ability to edit all textboxs. What I was thinking was to bring in the value, if the value is true then I would turn all the text boxes to read only.

I have seen this example:

```
private void DisableControls(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        DisableControls(c);
    }
    con.Enabled = false;
}
```

However I get red squiggly line under controls and again under Enabled. I will preface this by saying I am new to WPF.

Does anyone have a solution to this (or even a better way) any pointing in the right way would help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a view model that wraps your database models

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool MakeReadOnly {get;set;}
}
```

Reference your view model in the View

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
    ...>
    <Window.Resources>
         <local:MyViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    ...

</Window>
```

Bind the boolean value to your textboxes IsReadOnly property

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstName" IsReadOnly="{Binding MakeReadOnly">
  The user may not modify the contents of this TextBox if marked as readonly
</TextBox>

<TextBox x:Name="LastName" IsReadOnly="{Binding MakeReadOnly">
  The user may not modify the contents of this TextBox if marked as readonly
</TextBox>
```

More on View Models [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

Hope this helps!